# Understanding rails has_one has_many model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand a rails model association and having trouble figuring out what association I need to use:

Here's my app Models

`Company ----  Subscription ---- SubscriptionType`

The SubscriptionType has a list of 3 different types of subscriptions and their associated price.

A `Company has_one :subscription`.

A Subscription will `belong_to :company`.

It also has other fields, such as `trial_start_date`, `trial_end_date`, `charge_date`, etc.

At first, I thought that `Subscription has_one SubscriptionType` and `SubscriptionType has_many Subscriptions` however that relationship doesn't seem to work in my `subscription_spec.rb`

```
it { should have_one(:subscription_type) }
```

But that gives me the following error, which indicates that this relationship won't work since I don't want to have tons of records in the SubscriptionType table:

```
Expected Subscription to have a has_one association called subscription_type (SubscriptionType does not have a subscription_id foreign key.)
```

Can someone help me wrap my head around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `has_one` vs `belongs_to` is all about [where the foreign key lives](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one).

`Subscription has_one :subscription_type` means that `SubscriptionType` has a `subscription_id` column and belongs to only one `Subscription`.

`Subscription belongs_to :subscription_type` means that `Subscription` has a `subscription_type_id` column and `SubscriptionType` can belong to multiple `Subscription`s.

So to answer your question, the correct relationship here is

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription_type
end

class SubscriptionType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

Comment: Ok, that actually makes sense.  Maybe I was reading the RoR docs too long because it started to turn into Greek ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the associations like this:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :subscription
end

# subscriptions table should have columns company_id and subscription_type_id 
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :subscription_type
end

class SubscriptionType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

With this setup, the associated objects can be accessed as:

```
company = Company.find(1)
# to get subscription object with company_id: 1
company.subscription 
# to get subscription_type object of the company's associated subscription
company.subscription.subscription_type 
# to get all subscriptions of a particular subscription_type
SubscriptionType.last.subscriptions
```

Then, your `subscription_spec.rb` looks like:

```
it { should belong_to(:company) }
it { should belong_to(:subscription_type) }
```

Comment: Thanks for further clarifying!  Adam was first to the mat, so gave him credit... adding some cred to your answer though.